# How can I turn custom robot into a PROTO in Webots 2023?

Tags: webots

I created a custom robot using the Robot Node by importing some meshes and creating boundary boxes with primitive shapes. I want to use it in another world, and I know the process involves creating a Proto. My question is: How can I turn my robot into a PROTO? In the past, I remember that right-clicking the node would display the "**Export to Proto**" option. Is there a way to do this in **Webots 2023**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is to:

1. Open a text editor
2. Load the world file containing your Robot node in the text editor
3. Create a new PROTO file from scratch in the text editor
4. Copy your Robot node from the world file
5. Paste it in the body of your PROTO node

All this procedure is explained in detail in this [tutorial](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/tutorial-7-your-first-proto).

*Disclaimer: I am a [Webots](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots) developer working at [Cyberbotics](https://cyberbotics.com).*